# Compiler executing if statement randomly

Tags: c, gcc, file-io

I have following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *filename;
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    int i, number;

    fp1=fopen("TEST", "w");

    for(i=10; i<=100; i+=10)
    {
        putw(i, fp1);
    }

    fclose(fp1);

    printf("\nInput filename\n");

open_file:

    scanf("%s", filename);


    if((fp2=fopen(filename, "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open the file.\n");
        printf("Type file name again.\n");
        goto open_file;
    }

    else
    {
        for(i=1; i<=20; i++)
        {
            number=getw(fp2);

            if(feof(fp2))
            {
                printf("\nRan out of data\n");
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("%d\n", number);
            }
        }

        fclose(fp2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I inputed `TEST` for `scanf("%s", filename);`. But this statement `if((fp2=fopen(filename, "r"))==NULL)` is always executing and my compiler is printing `Cannot open the file` `Type file name again` randomly. Here is a `goto` statement. So it should wait for another input. But it is not. Where is the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *filename;` is a pointer and no memory is allocated for it.

Try

`char filename[100];` and give valid file name to work.

Comment: Wow!  It's working fine now. Would you please tell me why no memory is allocated for `char *filename`?

Comment: `char *filename` is a pointer meant for holding address of some char string. By default it will hold some garbage address.

Comment: read this tutorial on pointers http://karwin.blogspot.in/2012/11/c-pointers-explained-really.html

Comment: @Scotia `char *filename` just a pointer, you should allocate memory by define an array or using `malloc` or other function.

Comment: use `filename = malloc(100);`. It allocates 100 bytes and assigns the address to filename.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is  `scanf("%s", filename);` .
As filename is char pointer which is not allocated in your program (this non allocated pointer leads to undefined behavior). So you can either allocated pointer or use char array.

Answer (score 0):

From here [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), when you write `scanf("%s", filename);`, means you want to read an string and store the sting into `filename`, so the filename must be a arry(you should allocate memory for storing the string), but in you code you just write `char *filename;`, you don't allocate memory.